# I want to get a form and save it in local storage, but how?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, email, local-storage

Heyy,

i'm a beginner in writing with java script and i'm trying to copy Instagram, soo I need help in form and validation stuff and I also want to save it with local Storage.

I can't find the Problem in my Code and I don't know how to write the local Storage Code.

**scripts.js**

```
const VornameInput = document.getElementById("Vorname-input");
const NachnameInput = document.getElementById("Nachname-input");
const GeburtstagInput = document.getElementById("Geburtstag-input");
const ueberMichInput = document.getElementById("ueber-mich");
const SpeicherButton = document.getElementById("enter-button");
const EmailInput =document.getElementById("email-input");
const EingabeInput = document.getElementById("Eingabe");


SpeicherButton.addEventListener("click", enterEvent);

const Vorname = VornameInput.value;
const Nachname = NachnameInput.value;
const Geburtstag = GeburtstagInput.value;
const ueberMich = ueberMichInput.value;
const Email = EmailInput.value;



 function felderInKonsoleAusgeben () {
     console.log("Vorname:", Vorname);
     console.log("Nachname:", Nachname);
     console.log("Geburtstag:", Geburtstag);
     console.log("UeberMich:", ueberMich);
     console.log("Email:", EmailInput);
     
 }
     
function validierung(Vorname,Nachname,Geburtstag) {
    if (VornameInput.value == "" ||   NachnameInput.value == "" || isNaN(Number(GeburtstagInput.valueAsNumber))){
          alert ("Bitte fülle alle Felder aus! ");
          return false;
    }
    
    else 
        alert ("Eingaben wurden gespeichert");
        return true; }
 

        
function validierungEmail (EmailInput){

    var validRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
    
    if (input.value.match(validRegex)) {

        alert("Gültige Email Adresse!"); 
        return true;
} else {

    alert("Ungültige Email Adresse!");
    return false; }

   

function enterEvent(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    felderInKonsoleAusgeben();
    validierung(Vorname, Nachname, Geburtstag);
    validierungEmail(EmailInput); 
}
```

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="Das wird einmal ein Instagram Clone" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Instagram, Instagram 2.0, Clone" />
    <meta name="author" content="Emily Schlachter" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="scripts.js" defer></script>

    <title>Instagram 2.0</title>
  </head>

  <body>
      <header>
        <div > <a href="instagram-clone_schlachter.html"> <h1>Gramml</h1> </a ></div>
         </header> 

         <ul id="navibereich">
          <li id="navi01"> <a href="profil.html"> <h2>Mein Profil </h2> </a> </li>
          <li id="navi02"> <a href="instagram-clone_schlachter.html"> <h2>Entdecken</h2></a> </li>
          <li id="navi01"> <a href="upload.html"><h2>Upload Picture</h2></a> </li>
            </ul>

          <div class="label">
            <label>Suche:</label>
            <input type="text"/> 
            </div>

<main> 

 <!-- Eingabefeld -->

  
 <div class="Eingabe" id="Eingabe">
     
    <div class="field">
                          <input id="Vorname-input" type="text" name="vorname-input" placeholder="Vorname" />
      </div>

      <div class="field">
                          <input id="Nachname-input" type="text" name="Nachname-input " placeholder="Nachname" />
        </div>
    <div class="field">
                            <input id="email-input" type="text" name="email-input" placeholder="Email-Adresse" />
       </div>

        <div class="field">
                           <input id="Geburtstag-input" type="date" name="Geburtstag-input" placeholder="Geburtsdatum" />
      </div>

       

      <label>Über mich: <br> </label>  
      <textarea name="ueber-mich" id="ueber-mich" cols="40" rows="5" maxcols="35" placeholder="Über mich:"  > </textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="Formelles">   
      <p> <input type="checkbox" name="AGB" value="News"> Datenschutzerklärung und AGB akzeptieren. </p>  
      </div>
      
      <button id="enter-button" class=" button" type="submit">
       Speichern
    </button> 




</main>
</body>
  
</html>
```

I just want to get a validation formand to save the Input in local Storage.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please read [ask]. Provide a [mcve] (emphasis on *minimal*).

Comment: "I can't find the Problem in my Code" — Why do you think there is a problem with your code? What about its behaviour is different to what you expect? What errors are reported?

Comment: "I don't know how to write the local Storage Code" — Then start with [a tutorial on the subject](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=localstorage+tutorial&t=hc&va=g&ia=web).

Answer (score -1):

You can add all needed information into an obejct like

```
const personInfo = {
  "vorname": VornameInput.value,
  "nachname": ...,
  "geburtstag": ...,
  "uebermich": ...,
  "email": ...
}
```

Then you can store this object with a key in the local storage with

```
localStorage.setItem('personInfo',JSON.stringify(personInfo));
```

To get it back use

```
const pInfo = localStorage.getItem('personInfo');
```

Have a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage to learn more about localstorage